# How do i make any value display on the address bar when on get request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using( Html.BeginForm("Create", "Concepts", new  { name="sfsfsfsfsf", gio="sfsf9s9f0sffsdffs", ford="mtp"}, FormMethod.Get, null ) )
{
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="New" />
}
```

when i click the new button how do i show the values `gio`, `ford` and `name` on the URL?

this is my route definition

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Your adding route values, not query string values. You need to define a specific route, or add hidden inputs. Show your route definitions and the signature of the `Create` method (and you also need to remove `name="name"` from the button)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you got me there :) what are route definitions and their purpose

Comment: Add the code as per my first comment and I'll add an answer explaining what you have to do (your existing route definitions are defined in the `RouteConfig.cs` file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have the default URL setup this is for the MVC route address but how do i create a route for q regular query string

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want to drag this further assume i have a route address like http://localhost:17765/Product/GetAllProductsByCatId/1 when this was called display a products in a category it will pefrectly add all boostrap and displays things nicely but if i call the same product using query string http://localhost:17765/Product?GetAllProductsByCatId=1 this display the page but it has no bootstrap, why is this

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly relating to the question, but not sure I understand your last comment - your 2nd url could not possibly be calling the same method as the 1st one - to do so it would need to be `.../Product/GetAllProductsByCatId?id=1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103349/discussion-between-zeelong-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usage of `BeginForm()` is adding 3 route values, not query string values. If you want to generate a url which is `.../Concepts/Create/sfsfsfsfsf/sfsf9s9f0sffsdffs/mtp` which would go to (in `ConceptsController`)

```
public ActionResult Create(string name, string gio, string ford)
```

Then you need to add the following route definition (and it needs to be before the Default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Create",
    url: "Concepts/Create/{name}/{gio}/{ford}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Concepts", action = "Create" }
);
```

Note also that you need to remove `name="name"` from your submit button because of the conflict with the route parameter

Alternatively, if you want `.../Concepts/Create?name=sfsfsfsfsf@&gio=sfsf9s9f0sffsdffs&ford=mtp`, then remove the route parameters and add inputs for the values

```
@using( Html.BeginForm("Create", "Concepts", FormMethod.Get) )
{
    <input name="name" value="sfsfsfsfsf" />
    <input name="gio" value="sfsf9s9f0sffsdffs" />
    <input name="ford" value="mtp" />
    <input type="submit" value="New" />
}
```